# Limit of ratio of two Radon measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I've just encountered the following exercise:

Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ be a locally compact metric space. Let $\nu$, $\mu$ be two Radon measures on $X$. Suppose that:

(i) $w \in L^1(X,\mu)$, $w \ge 0 $ a.e on $X$.

(ii) $w$ is continuous at $x_0$.

(iii) $\nu(A)=\int_{A} w \, d \mu$ for every $A \in \mathcal{M}$, that is $w=\frac{d \nu}{d \mu}$.

Prove that:

$$ \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{\nu(B(x_0,r))}{\mu(B(x_0,r))}=w(x_0)$$.

The statement seems very familiar when $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ $\mu \equiv \mathcal{L}$  (Lebesgue measure) since it's the Lebesgue differentiation theorem (or even the FTC since $w$ is continuous, if $n=1$). But in this general case I cannot quite get to the point: I've tried a standard $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument that seems not working due to a $\frac{1}{\mu(B(x_0,r))}$ I cannot control just with the continuity of $w$ at $x_0$. How to attack the problem in this general case?

My attempt:

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. By the continuity of $w$ at $x_0$ we can find a $\delta > 0$ such that $|w(x)-w(x_0)| \le \epsilon $ whenever $ x \in B(x_0, \delta)$. It follows:

$$ \left| \frac{\nu(B(x_0,r))}{\mu(B(x_0,r))}-w(x_0) \right| \le  \frac{1}{\mu(B(x_0,r)} \int_{B(x_0,r)} |w(x)-w(x_0)| \, d \mu \le \frac{1}{\mu(B(x_0,r)} \int_{B(x_0,\delta)} |w(x)-w(x_0)| \, d \mu \le \epsilon \frac{\mu(B(x_0,\delta))}{\mu(B(x_0,r))} $$, provided $|r| < \delta$.

Comment: What can you say about $ \nu(B(x_0,r))$ when $r$ is small, using the continuity of $w$ and the monotinicity of integrals?

Comment: I'll edit the post with my full attempt.

Comment: You should also assume $\mu(B(x_0,r))>0$ for every $r$ to have a well-defined ratio

Comment: Oh, true, I forgot about that, thanks.

Comment: Use that $\int_{B(x_0,r)}|w(x)-w(x_0)|d\mu\leq \mu(B(x_0,r))\epsilon$ for $r$ small enough. This allows to simplify the last term and obtain just $\epsilon$.